# UIViewController's background color becomes transparent when pushing another UIViewController that contains a PDFView [Obj-c]

Tags: objective-c, pdfkit

I'm currently working on a small app that displays a view controller (`PDFViewController`) that contains a `PDFView` when a cell in my first view controller (`HomeViewController`) is clicked. I set the background color of the `PDFViewController` to be a light gray color in its initializer, but when I push it to my navigation controller, it still appears transparent (I can still see the cells from the `HomeViewController`).

Here's an image of what's happening. This is the screen shot of when I move the `PDFView` downward and slightly to the right.

[image]

How can I get it so that the view behind this `PDFView` is just a light gray color?

This is my initializer for `PDFViewController`:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor;
        // setup PDF view
        self.selctedPDF = PDFView.new;
        self.selctedPDF.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:self.selctedPDF];
        [self.selctedPDF.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
        [self.selctedPDF.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor].active = YES;
        [self.selctedPDF.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor].active = YES;
        [self.selctedPDF.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is how I'm presenting the `PDFViewController`:

```
PDFViewController *viewPDF = [[PDFViewController alloc] init];
viewPDF.selctedPDF.document = [self.pdfs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].doc;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewPDF animated:YES];
```

Comment: I think light grey colour not added, that's why background view is visible. Am i correct.

Comment: @iOS yes, although i set it equal to light gray, it seems to remain clear.

Comment: Here (self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor;) this self.view is related to PDFViewController main view. Am i correct

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: You directly add background colour in PDFViewController viewDidLoad(), it can work. If not share your code to me